# Count, Join or possibly GROUP By

Tags: sql, join, count, group-by

So i have made simple query that gives me total sum of cases where was mentioned PassportNumber = 'C_AA8'. But it will return 0 if i`ll set query for PassportNumber that doesnt exist in RegistrationCase(as i understand it cant JOIN).
How can i fix it? And there is a way to remake this query to work with GROUP BY ?
Thank for any further assistance.
I am using MySQL with PHPmyadmin and AMPPS. Fixed register.

```
SELECT COUNT( unRegisterCase.PassportNumber ) + COUNT( RegistrationCase.PassportNumber ) + COUNT( RecoveringCase.NewPassportNumber ) AS result
FROM RegistrationCase
LEFT JOIN unRegisterCase ON unRegisterCase.PassportNumber = RegistrationCase.Passportnumber
LEFT JOIN RecoveringCase ON RecoveringCase.NewPassportNumber = RegistrationCase.Passportnumber
WHERE RegistrationCase.PassportNumber =  'C_AA8'
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by `it will return 0 if i'll set query for PassportNumber that doesnt exist in RegistrationCase`? If it does not exist that means count is zero, isn't it? can you show some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Thank for your replay Kaf. In comments below i got already 'fixed' version of mine query.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it?

```
SELECT COUNT(PassportNumber ) as PassportCount FROM
(
SELECT PassportNumber FROM RegistrationCase UNION ALL
SELECT NewPassportNumber FROM RecoveringCase UNION ALL
SELECT PassportNumber FROM unRegisterCaseber
) A
WHERE PassportNumber =  'C_AA8'
```

Comment: This seems to work fine, or even perfect. Thanks, gonna test it more! Is there a way to make similar query with usage of GROUP BY ?

Comment: Why do you want to use `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Thank you for replying to me Hamlet Hakobyan. By real - i dont want to use it or even i dont see how it can be used but got task to make query that will return same results as yours above but with usage of GROUP BY. (Probably calculating sums from 3 tables seperate and then GROUP BY them) So i am asking is there a way to realize this and how it can look?

Comment: @user1899717: GROUP BY would make sense if you wanted to find and return counts for more than one passport number (perhaps, for all of them). In that case you would specify in the outer query: `GROUP BY PassportNumber`, and add `PassportNumber` to the outer SELECT clause, to display the passport numbers and their corresponding counts.

Comment: If you add `GROUP BY PassportNumber` to the query, the result will remain unchanged.

Comment: Andriy M thanks for clarification. Hamlet Hakobyan, yes, it worked bu t it doesnt make any sense to add it there like that;(

Answer (score 0):

well with the where clause at the bottom of the SQl it cancels out the left joins,

try this out

```
 SELECT COUNT( UnregisterCase.PassportNumber ) + 
        COUNT( RegistrationCase.PassportNumber ) + 
        COUNT( RecoveringCase.NewPassportNumber ) AS result
 FROM RegistrationCase, unRegisterCase, RecoveringCase
 WHERE UnregisterCase.PassportNumber = RegistrationCase.Passportnumber
 AND RecoveringCase.NewPassportNumber = RegistrationCase.Passportnumber
 AND RegistrationCase.PassportNumber =  'C_AA8'
```

Also check for case sensitivity since you have different spellings of unRegister and Unregister

Comment: This won't work either if there are no matching RegistrationCase rows.